# How many bytes should I use in openssl_random_pseudo_bytes

Tags: php, security, passwords, openssl, secret-key

I want to generate a 40 bytes random password with

```
k = ???
password = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(k))
```

What would be the recommended value of k so password is strong enough?

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on Security Stack Exchange. But like @thejh said, SHA1 is the weak link in the chain. So it does not matter if you put 20 bytes in or 1024 bytes in, you're only getting 20 bytes out. Also, you should be using a `HMAC`, not a hash, because a `HMAC` is a Pseudo Random Function (PRF) with provable security properties. Since you are using OpenSSL, you might also look at PBKDF. You can use it on non-password secrets, too. See [How to use PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771212/how-to-use-pkcs5-pbkdf2-hmac-sha1).

Comment: Also, OpenWall's [phppass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) might be of interest to you. Alexander has taken care of most of the details for you. It may not be a good fit at all, either. Its hard to say without seeing requirements.

Answer (score 2):

SHA1 outputs 20 bytes, so giving it 20 bytes of random input should be enough. Think of it like this: An attacker could either try to guess passwords or try to guess SHA1 inputs. As long as the SHA1 input is at least as long as the output, it's easier for him to just brueforce the outputs, so the input is long enough.

However, I'm wondering about why you're using SHA1 on those random bytes at all. [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) should already give you random bytes that you can simply convert to hex using [`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.bin2hex.php) or so.